# Inverse Fourier Transforms in Matlab

Tags: matlab, fft

I've been given the Magnitude and Phase from a Fourier Transform and now I'm asked to use these matrices to go backwards and reproduce the image again. Thus far here is my understanding:

```
%Here we have the imaginary part
z = Mag.*cos(Phase) + 1i.*sin(Phase);

%Here we get the real part
real = sqrt((Mag).^2-(z).^2);

image = ifftshift(real);
image = ifft(image);

imshow(image);
```

I take the Magnitude and Phase and get the imaginary part. Then I use the Magnitude formula i.e. `Mag = sqrt((real)^2+(imaginary)^2)` to try solve for the real part. I then do reverse shifts and a reverse fourier transform in hopes of getting the image... but I get:

[image]

I really need help figuring this out, any ideas?

Comment: All you need to do is take the IFFT of `z`.  You don't need to do the IFFT of the `real` part by itself.  You are also missing a multiplication of `Mag` for the imaginary term.  @vsoftco has it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computation of real part and imaginary part is not correct. I'd do this:

```
z = Mag.*cos(Phase) + 1i*Mag.*sin(Phase); % full matrix of complex amplitudes 

%Here we get the real part
real_part = real(z);
imag_part = imag(z); % do you need this at all?!

image = ifftshift(real_part); % not sure why you are doing this
image = ifft(image);

imshow(image);
```

Comment: If the OP wants to reconstruct the image, all he/she really needs to do is take the IFFT of `z` (your corrected one).  I don't know why he/she is decomposing into the real and imaginary parts then undoing the transformation after, so I agree with your comments.